# The order of reading bits in blocks

Tags: key-size

Let's say I have a cryptographic algorithm that encrypts on 128-bit blocks and makes 20 rounds. Each round has its own keys (one of 72 keys per round). We read blocks before each round. But we're introducing the bit reading order. We can read from the most significant bit or the least significant bit. But in total we can read the bits before each round at 128! ways. We only need to define 20 random 128-element permutations.

But this increases the keys, you need to store these permutations. Is it a good idea?

For the safety of this algorithm there must be some order of bit reading, we can't always read them according to a typical binary number reading scheme.

Answer (score 1):

> But this increases the keys, you need to store these permutations. Is it a good idea?

I wouldn't think so; not so much from a subkey storage perspective, but from a performance perspective.

Storage could be do-able; $\log_2 128! \approx 716.16$; $20$ of these could be stored in $1791$ bytes, although it is likely that you wouldn't store them in a storage-minimal way, but instead in a format that makes it more efficient to perform the 20 permutations.

On the other hand, performance would look to be hideous.  There isn't an obvious way for software to permute 128 bits in a random fashion efficiently; picking each bit up, and depositing it in target position is unthinkably slow.  About the best I can think of would be to emulate a Batcher sort of the 128 bits (with appropriate masks to control when you swap and when you don't) - that's still likely to be slow (especially when you consider you need to do it 20 times).

As for hardware, well, by throwing a large number of gates at the problem, you could make it run reasonably fast - however, there are a lot of better ways to speed up other ciphers if you have a lot of gates at your disposal.

Why do I say performance is important?  Well, if you don't care about performance, it's easy to design things that are quite secure (e.g. 8-AES-256, using 8 independent keys); unless your design has some advantage over that, your cipher would appear to be pointless.

Comment: I thought that picking each bit and depositing it in target position is quite fast. You need to only read some random permutation:

2 5 7 13 155 121 11 71...

and then put first bit on second position, second bit on fifth position and so on. But these are only my intuitions, may be bad (I'm not a programmer).

If we will read bits in normal order, like binary numbers (the cipher must do calculations on them), then it can be as fast as AES (more or less). But these advantages will be lost if bit reading is very slow. Maybe it's better to mix bits in blocks somehow, I will think about it.

Comment: @Tom: picking and depositing a single bit is fairly fast.  Doing it 128 times per round turns "fairly fast" into "quite slow" (and then you do that 20 times, one per round), and that turns it into "hideously slow"

Comment: But how about xoring blocks with random key before each round will start? It shuould give the same or similar result. And XOR is fast.

Comment: @Tom: how well that works would depend entirely on your round function.  Note that XORing key dependent values does nothing to disrupt either linear or differential characteristics; your round function would need to be strong against those

Comment: Round functions are very sensitive to bit order. So I think that small differences in input can cause large differences in output. These are very nonlinear functions themselves. Very similar to collatz sequences. I will investigate this problem.